# How to get results of File reader

Tags: javascript, angular, file, reader

So I have an onchange event in my html which gets an image from the user and need to convert it to a data url in order to send over socket.io and store in the database. How do I get the results of my file reader object. I dont know how to pass in a callback

What I need to do is get a callback function into the file reader onload event so that I can set my picture variable to the data url to then send over the socket. Just need help in getting the results from the file reader to my global variable
// HTML

```
<input type = 'file' (change) = "setpreview($event)" value = 'upload photo'>
```

// the js code.

```
setpreview(event) {
  var img = <File>event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(img);
}
```

Comment: That's because you're only declaring the `reader` variable in your `setpreview` method, which will not exist outside of the function scope as what the error indicates.

Comment: is there a way to get a callback function into the setpreview function? I tried doing it through html but that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it just assign the result to a scoped variable and use it in template

```
srcImg = null; //declare this

setpreview(event) {
  const comp = this;
  const img = <File>event.target.files[0];
  const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      resolve(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
  });

  promise.then(img => {
    comp.srcImg = img;
    // if you want to do anything with img you can do it here
  });
}
```

```
<input type = 'file' (change) = "setpreview($event)" value = 'upload photo'>
<img [src]="srcImg" *ngIf="srcImg" />
```

Updated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkbbdh

Comment: You are an absolute god send, Had no idea you could have a variable act as an interface for your other scoped variables. Thank you so much !

Comment: glad it worked. I added a promise so that you can store it in db or anywhere, you can extract the logic in a different method maybe if you like but you can do your activities in reader.onload function and lose the promise if it doesn't; mean anything to you.